# Can someone help me identify the handwritten kanji?

Tags: kanji, handwriting, writing-identification

[image]

Hi everyone, can someone please help me identify the kanji in the picture? Just the middle two kanji.
玲音がXXしているもの。
Is the kanji 使用?

Also what is the middle katakana/character between ミ and レ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the kanji are 使用

The middle character is the 長音記号{ちょうおんきごう} sound extending mark「ー」and the word is シール (seal, as in stamp or sticker). Note that the bottom stroke of the シ angles up not down.